# Rename/move function in Perl not giving results

Tags: perl, rename, move

I have a file which I need to move to a specific folder and rename while doing so.

```
use File::Copy "move";
print rename('D:\\Test\\Input\\temp.cxx','D:\\Test\\Input\\new.cxx'), die $! ;
```

But this gives me error saying "Permission denied at D:\Test\Test.pl line 35,  line 5899". I am running as admin. Even all the folders have full permissions.

**Update**
It is working now. I had one of the files open on a line before this line. Once I closed it, rename works. But if I store the path in variables it again gives me the same error.

Comment: first of all, make sure the file isn't open in any other program. after you do that, try opening cmd in administrator mode and run your script from there. it should work

Comment: @lonut - As I said, I am running the cmd as Administrator. Thats my whole issue. No matter what it aint working!

Comment: Try using double quotes or making your slashes forward slashes.

Comment: @squiguy - I tried that! I am windows. So I was not using forward slashes. But still it doesnt work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a couple of problems here.

First, you're using File::Copy but not using anything from it.  The `rename` function is part of core Perl.

Second, you're printing the return value from `rename` which is probably not meaningful.  It returns a true or false value.

Third, you're always `die`ing, regardless of the return status of the move.

Fourth, all those backslashes are prone to error.

I think what you might be intending is more like this:

```
rename('D:/Test/Input/temp.cxx','D:/Test/Input/new.cxx') or die "Unable to rename: $!";
```

That may help expose your permissions problem.

Comment: Sorry. It is not working still. I think there is some problem with my PC. Let me try on another PC and get back.

Comment: Thanks. It is working now. I had one of the file open on a line before this line. Once I closed it, rename works. But if I store the path in variables it again gives me the same error.

Comment: @CamelCase Windows has the well intentioned feature where open files have [mandatory locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking#In_Microsoft_Windows). If you (or something else) has a file open for writing, you will not be able to move it no matter if you're the administrator or not. Its very important on Windows to close your filehandles, using lexical filehandles (ie. `open( my $fh, ... )` helps a lot as they close when the file goes out of scope.

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys. But have another problem. The normal rename where we give strings as input works fine. but if I do something like this 

rename($oldName,$newName)

It doesn't work! Any ideas why this would be the case?

Comment: Not without seeing the code, no.  You can't just give a summary or paraphrase of non-working code.  You need to show all the code.

Answer (score 1):

As Andy said, no need for File::Copy in your example, unless your using 'move' somewhere else?  The following worked perfectly on my Win7 machine with Activestate Perl 5.14.2:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
rename "C:\\Users\\JLBlack\\test.txt", "C:\\Users\\JLBlack\\test.new" or die "rename failed because: $!\n";
exit();
```

Are you sure the destination doesn't already exist?  And it's not open/used by anything else?  Can you move the file from the Windows command prompt?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I had a colon in the new filename. This is forbidden on Windows, but Windows normally tells you that. If your interface is something like Perl, apparently all that gets through is "permission denied".